# Rewriting an equation of the form $\frac{a-b}{c-b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, functions

I have some sampled data, from which I calculated means of each group and am then using those estimates as input to a formula. I am currently calculating the corresponding error propagation formula in order to obtain a metric of error on this final estimation.

The initial formula contains the term: $$\frac{a-b}{c-b}$$ I need to rewrite this equation so that I am only using a single $b$ value and therefore have uncorrelated errors. Is there a way to rewrite the above so I am only inputting a single instance of $a$, $b$, and $c$ into the formula?

Thank you!

Comment: You can write $$\frac{a-b}{c-b}=1+\frac{a-c}{c-b}$$ This uses only one instance of $b$

Answer (score 0):

You can, but in terms of two fractions

$$\frac{a-b}{c-b}=\frac{a}{c-b}-\frac{b}{c-b}$$

Then if $b\neq 0$ you can write

$$\frac{a-b}{c-b}=\frac{a}{c-b}-\frac{1}{\frac{c}{b}-1}$$

Comment: Thanks for your response! Only issue is that I still have multiple instances of c and b in this equation. I am basing my reasoning off of the approach outlined [here](http://ipl.physics.harvard.edu/wp-uploads/2013/03/PS3_Error_Propagation_sp13.pdf); see pg. 4 about the issue of uncorrelated errors. Consequently, I need to rewrite this equation in such a way that I am only using each term once.